# ハンドトラッキングのサンプルアプリをターミナルでビルドできない

Tags: ios, tensorflow

以下↓の記事を再現しようとしています。

[MediaPipeのハンドトラッキング(iOS)をXcodeプロジェクトでビルドしてみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ponte1010/items/13249df5dab8fadea88f)

しかし、ターミナルでハンドトラッキングをビルドするところで以下のようにエラーが出ます。

```
$ bazel build -c opt –config=ios_arm64 mediapipe/example/ios/handtrackinggpu:HandTrackingGpuApp
ERROR: Skipping '–config=ios_arm64': Bad target pattern '–config=ios_arm64': package names may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or any of ' !"#$%&'()*+,-./;<=>?[]^_`{|}~' (most 7-bit ascii characters except 0-31, 127, ':', or '\')
ERROR: Bad target pattern '–config=ios_arm64': package names may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or any of ' !"#$%&'()*+,-./;<=>?[]^_`{|}~' (most 7-bit ascii characters except 0-31, 127, ':', or '\')
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.170s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

どのように解決できますでしょうか？

Hello World desktop exampleの動作確認、Provisioning Profileの設置、Bundle identifierの変更は済んでおります。
ipaファイルは作成されておりません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: bazel のバージョンを確認してみるとよいかもしれません。 - "If you use Bazel 1.2.1+, please downgrade Bazel" [Handtracking GPU build failing for iOS](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/534#issuecomment-600769780)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
BazelのバージョンをTensorFlowに対応した1.1.0にダウングレードしたのですが、全く同じエラーが出ております。
他に考えられる点があれば教えていただけますと幸いです。